# First countable spaces, enumerable neighborhood base system

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space then $X$ is first countable if for every $x \in X$ there exists a neighborhood base system $\mathcal{B}_x$ that is enumerable. Does this means that $$\mathcal{B}_x = \{ V_n \, : \, n \in \Bbb N \},$$ each $V_n$ being a basic neighborhood of $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the definition of being enumerable. One also denotes this as $\{ V_n(x) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, if you want to be explicit about the fact that these are the elements of $\mathcal{B}_x$.